# Include Restrictive License on Take Home Project

Tags: interviewing, job-search, test

I was given a take home test after an interview that took me a lot of time to complete. The project includes an API, realtime database backend and a mobile frontend with remote notifications.

Is there a software license I can include that would compensate me or prevent the potential employer from using my code in a future project if I don't get the job? I'm expecting to get an offer after submitting the project but I've done these tests before and want to protect myself.

Comment: This might be helpful https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276340/licensing-code-submitted-after-job-interview

Comment: This as well https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98619/submit-code-during-interview

Comment: Don't know others, but this sounds to me like quite a "big" project to be asked to do as a *code test*, even more if it's "take home"... I advice to be cautious to avoid being used as free dev work

Comment: The best option for all of us is to not do the project. Fight the good fight!

Comment: If it's a competent company, they've already had their staff programmers do the task, and your test will be "graded" by comparing it to theirs.

Comment: @DarkCygnus It is a big project, I feel I've proven myself and now have some leverage in negotiations or I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @jcmack I wish I could!

Comment: @WesleyLong I don't think that's the case here, this is a new position for a mobile dev. I don't think there is anyone in the company that can do it, in fact, I think there are very few in the city that can do it.

Comment: I occasionally hear about claims where people say their interview tests were used as unpaid "work". Has this ever been proven anywhere? I find it hard to believe that a company would go through a fake interview process just to get a few hours of "free work". Moreover, suppose one did have a "restrictive" license, how would that be enforced? Are victims willing to spend thousands of dollars and weeks of effort to get a lawyer busy for a tenuous chance at success?

Comment: @teego1967 It's free consulting. The company gets to see a number of different approaches to solve a problem. Depending on the problem being solved (see newguy's link) you could be giving an algorithm that makes the company a lot of money and it may be worth legal action.

Answer (score 2):

**If they didn't pay you for the project, then the code likely belongs to you.  Be careful about NDAs**

The code likely belongs to you unless they paid you, or you used company resources.  The company may be unhappy that you leaked their "Confidential Candidate Assessment" test.  [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/) and sites like it explicitly share interview questions from companies like Google, Facebook, etc, which make candidates sign NDAs, I've never heard of any company going after recruits who post questions and answers.

Honestly, any remotely reasonable company likely already assumes previous candidates have posted the answers.  They (hopefully) change the test up a bit to make sure you can't just cut-and-paste.

Comment: I did use my personal computer and XCode by default includes a copyright header. I did not sign any NDA or agreement.

Comment: Then it's almost certainly yours (I'm not a lawyer, FYI)